# Responsive layout. Same html for desktop + mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm building a responsive front with Bootstrap 4 and I can't do what I want.

I made the result I want on codepen but I'm trying to avoid duplicate code for desktop+mobile.

```
<p>On desktop</p>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-3">
      <div class="picture">PICTURE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-8 ">
          <div class="content-a">ContentA</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-4">
          <div class="button">Button</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-12">
          <div class="content-b">Content B</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>On mobile</p>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      <div class="picture">PICTURE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      <div class="content-a">Contant A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-12">
      <div class="content-b">Contant B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-12">
      <div class="button">Button</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/sanchou/pen/YzyXaQW

Is this possible to make? How could I achieve that?

Comment: you are trying to make responsive design for mobile and desktop alright

Comment: with bootstrap I don't know if it's possible to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider implementing your layout using flexbox: 
[Bootstrap Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/)

You can change the order of 'Content B' and 'Button' using [order class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#order).

Keep in mind that some older browsers might not support it though.